# I can't center H1 in header using flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to learn flexbox and I am struggling with centering the text in a div in the header.  I have an image on the left and then a dif with a text_box and I'm trying to center the h1 using justify-content: center but no matter what I put there it will not mvoe the text.  The only way I can get the text to center is by using margin: 0 auto; but that seems to be more to the right as well.

Code:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.7;
    color: #777;
    padding: 20px;
}

.header {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    height: 60vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        to right bottom,
        rgba(12, 186, 186, 0.5), 
        rgba(56, 0, 54, 0.5)),
        url(../img/code.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 55vh, 0 100%);
   /* Defines how to distribute the empty space between child elements */
   color: #fff;
   padding: 40px;

}

.header_img img {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 82%;
    padding: 0;
}

.header_text {
    justify-content: center  
}



hr {
    display: flex;

}

@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
    .text_box h1 {
      font-size: 1.4em;
    }
    .text_box h2 {
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }

    .header {
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .header_img {
        display: flex;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
     <header class="header">
        <div class="header_img">
           <img src="assets/img/stephen_moore_london_2012.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <<div class="header_text">
               <h1>My Name</h1>
               <hr>
               <h2>Something Here</h2>
        </div>
    </header>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the header_text class:

```
.header_text {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can center the text for a given element. Here I removed all the excess just to show the text - I added borders for clarity on what is where and to show the content can get out with what you have

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #777;
  padding: 20px;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-items: center;
  height: 60vh;
  padding: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.header-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-items: center;
  border: 1px solid lime;
  width: 100%;
}

.header-text h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="header_img">
      <img src="assets/img/stephen_moore_london_2012.jpg" alt="I do not exist">
    </div>
    <div class="header-text">
      <h1>My Name</h1>
      <hr>
      <h2>Something Here</h2>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn’t actually work.

Comment: @StephenScottMoore - run the snippet here - it does center the `<h1>` which was the question title.  I added `alt` text for the non-existent image  which may add clarity to what I did.  It may help to have more clarity in the question re: "dif with a text_box " has no context in your question - and when you desire "center" did/do you mean the entire block and each or just the H! as stated?